# Customising UITableView

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I'm playing with Xcode/Interface Builder and I'm able to build simple Navigation apps. I'm wondering how the guys at TapBots manage to get their table views themed like this:

http://tapbots.com/img/software/convertbot/screenshot_05.jpg
(http://tapbots.com/software/convertbot/#gallery)

I've tried setting backgrounds on tables, but I lose the rounded corners. 
Is this an easy thing to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The Tapbots developer spent around 6 months writing a customised UI library, which is what you see there.

It's basically a reimplementation of UIKit with personalised styling.

Comment: Ouch. Out of my reach for now then :)
Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Oliver H: It depends on what you want to do. If you just want to do group, accessory. Or change color of cell and table view background. you can still do it. Absolutely not the same level at the theme